# Trust regions cause optimization problem to blow up

Tags: convergence-divergence, optimization, convex-optimization, second-order-cone-programming

I’ve seen many papers (for example, [this](https://stanford.edu/class/ee364b/lectures/seq_slides.pdf) one on sequential convex programming) where non-convex problems are solved with convex optimization methods by first linearizing the problem at iteration $k$ about the solution given at iteration $k-1$, and implementing a trust region constraint where $|x^{k}-x^{k-1}|\leq\delta$ in order to make convergence to a solution more robust. However, I recently tried to use a trust region constraint in a problem that used a sequential convex programming approach, and found that without the trust region constraint it converged to a stable solution, but with a trust region constraint, the problem blew up, giving me NaN values (using MATLAB) after the first iteration.

I used the following additional constraint in my problem:

```
abs(xk - xkm1) <= delta
```

where `xk` is the state vector of the current iteration, `xkm1` is the state vector of the previous iteration, and `delta` is the maximum allowable change in states between iterations $k$ and $k-1$.

I thought that trust regions were supposed to increase convergence robustness, but it seems that I’ve somehow achieved the opposite result by adding the simple constraint given above. I’m hoping it’s just a trivial mistake I’ve made somewhere, so thought I’d see if trust regions causing problems to blow up are common with beginners in this field.

Comment: So how are you actually implementing this (you're adding a non-smooth constraint in the model, does the solver actually work well with that kind of models...)

Comment: I'm using the Mosek solver with an optimization package called YALMIP. Many papers that implement the sequential convex programming and trust region combination seem to use the same setup, so I would assume that adding a trust region would not be a problem.

Comment: How did you determine $\delta$?  Is it so small that the solver can't really optimize over the tiny feasible region?  Is it so large that the problem is effectively unconstrained?  Could it be that YALMIP has switched to a different solver after the constraints were added and that the new solver isn't working well?

Comment: You should post that question n the YALMIP forum instead, with reproducible code (I am the YALMIP developer). Typical problem is that the solution you have at some iteration is infeasible due to numerical tolerances, causing the next iteration to be infeasible from start.

Comment: It's funny, he asked this question in the CVX forum, and I sent him here ;-) There was no actual code in the question so there's really nothing we can do but talk about generalities, which is not the purpose of that forum. But yes, if there is specific code to share, that's another matter.

Comment: Hi Michael (I see Johan of YALMIP is also here, hello), I'd love to share the code, but it is a few hundred lines and I don't think it'll be practical to put it all here. Unfortunately, I also won't be able to cut it down to a more compact version and still be able to show the dynamics accurately. I could send the full code to you and others if you're willing to have me email it over, though. Would that work?